# BrowserSync.stream() not working, browserSync.reload() throws error

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

This is my Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    simplevars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nested = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('default', function() {   
  console.log("Test to see if gulp is running");
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  console.log("Something happening to my html");
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
  .pipe(postcss([cssImport, simplevars, nested, autoprefixer]))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
});

gulp.task('cssInject', ['styles'], function() {
  return gulp.src('.app/temp/styles/styles.css')
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify:false,
    server: {
      baseDir: "app"
    }
  });

  watch('./app/index.html', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
  });

  watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', function() {
    gulp.start('cssInject');
  });
});
```

When I run the `gulp watch` task, `index.html` file reloads as expected. But the `cssInject task` does not reload the page, nor does it inject the css changes. It does nothing. If I change the `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` to `.pipe(browserSync.reload());`, it reloads + updates the changes, but I get this error:

```
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[11:15:36] 'cssInject' errored after 22 ms
[11:15:36] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:516:7)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\gulpfile.js:34:4)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
    at finish (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
    at f (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at C:\Users\z\OneDrive\NewWebsite\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

EDITED to add: I have version 2.12.8 of browser-sync.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `{ stream: true }` to `.reload()`:

```
return gulp.src('.app/temp/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
```

And change

Comment: Tried that but it still doesn't reload the page. The changes are reflected when I manually reload the page but it doesn't get triggered automatically.

Comment: @newbie Maybe changing this? `watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', 'cssInject');`

Comment: I think I fixed it. I created another gulp task (bs-reload) just with browserSync.reload() with cssInject as a dependency. I then used gulp to start bs-reload instead of cssInject in the gulp watch task. It reloads the page. I don't know why and I don't know how to make the browserSync stream work, but it will have to do for now.

Comment: In your cuss watch task you call gulp.start : there is no gulp.start in the documentation.

Comment: Just a quick note, on my environment (Visual Studio 2017/Gulp 4.0.0/Browser-Sync 2.3.2), I had to change it to lowercase: `.pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream: true }));`.

Comment: @AnthonyWalsh it's a variable name. The name and its casing are determined by you, not your environment.

Comment: You are dead right @Corey, thanks for pointing that out. For others new to Gulp like me, I  originally declared the "`var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();`" at the head of the Gulp file as _lowercase_) and so when I pasted the code from this answer of course it didn't match the Camel case `browserSync`. Silly me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues - as noted in my comment you used gulp.start.  Try

```
gulp.watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', ['styles']);

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, simplevars, nested, autoprefixer]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});
```

I combined your 'cssInject' task and 'styles' task since you could do what you wanted in one task easier.  The browserSync.reload call will try to inject the changed files if it can rather than reloading the page.  There are some good gulp and browserSync recipes at [official gulp recipes for css injection.](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/server-with-livereload-and-css-injection.md)